# How to set UTF-8 in Vue.js, correctly?

Tags: vue.js

Using Vue.js and Vue-meta, I configured utf-8 in my App.vue as follow:

```
    metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: 'My',
            titleTemplate: '%s | Titulo',
            meta: [
                { equiv: 'Content-Type', content: 'text/html; charset=utf-8' },
                { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }                 

            ]
        }
    },
```

But is not working, when my webpage is rendered, tildes, accents are not setted. 
For example, these symbols always are showed �, instead ó.  "Integraci�n".

How can I configure this issue?

Could you help me with this issue, please?
Thks

Comment: I think it's named http-equiv instead of equiv. Alternatively you could specify the content-type in your html file

Comment: Can you not just include `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your `index.html` file? That's typically how it comes out of the box with Vue CLI

Comment: I can not, because I do not have index.html file. My application uses other way to use Vue.js. I mean, I use App.vue, main.js, router, and so on. So, I made my own components Home.vue, Contact.Vue . By the way, I am using Asp.net Core and MVC. So far, What other suggestion do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `charset=utf-8` into it's own object within the `meta` array:

```
    metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: 'My',
            titleTemplate: '%s | Titulo',
            meta: [
                { charset: 'utf-8' },
                { equiv: 'Content-Type', content: 'text/html' },
                { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }                 

            ]
        }
    },
```